# Exception : Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: asset

Tags: java, android

I am reading the .OBJ file which is in asset folder. But I am getting exception while reading the file. Even I debug the project on eclipse but I could find the reason for this.

Please help me

Thanks in advance.

```
/**
 * Load Object Asynchronous.
 * @author Ajay
 */
private class ObjLoaderAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        try {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(localContext);
            progressDialog.setTitle(localContext
                    .getString(R.string.app_name));
            progressDialog.setMessage(localContext
                    .getString(R.string.please_wait));
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            mr[getCurrentPosition()] = new ModelRenderer(localContext,
                    localContext.getAssets().open(RendererView.objName));
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            Log.v("DemoRendererView", "loading model: " + e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
        try {
            progressDialog.cancel();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}

public ModelRenderer(Context paramContext, InputStream localFileInputStream) throws FileNotFoundException {
    ModelStaticClassTransfer.value = -777.0F;
    while (true) {
        try {
            i = localFileInputStream.read();
            if (i != -1)
                continue;
            localFileInputStream.close();
            if ((char) i == 'v') {
                i = localFileInputStream.read();
                if ((char) i != ' ')
                    continue;
                this.verticeCounter = (1 + this.verticeCounter);
                continue;
            }
            if ((char) i == 'f') {
                i = localFileInputStream.read();
                if ((char) i != ' ')
                    continue;
                this.indexCounter = (1 + this.indexCounter);
                continue;
            }
            int j = localFileInputStream.read();
            i = j;
        } catch (IOException localIOException) {
            localIOException.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Error Trace

```
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: asset
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.readAssetChar(Native Method)
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.access$200(AssetManager.java:35)
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949):    at android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.read(AssetManager.java:548)
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949):    at com.amplimesh.models.ModelRenderer.<init>(ModelRenderer.java:64)
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949):    at com.amplimesh.models.ModelGLRenderer$ObjLoaderAsync.doInBackground(ModelGLRenderer.java:138)
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949):    at com.amplimesh.models.ModelGLRenderer$ObjLoaderAsync.doInBackground(ModelGLRenderer.java:1)
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-12 12:54:57.516: E/AndroidRuntime(29949):    ... 5 more
```

Comment: the error is in the native assetManager, meaning that the asset is opened all right, but there is an issue after that. To identify the issue with more precision, I suggest you make a very simple app that only reads the file from the assets. This would tell you if the issue is with the file itself.

Comment: I used the same file in different project. It was working in that project.

Comment: what is `localContext`. May be it is due to getAsset() returns null. and when you are opening a `null` object (i.e accessing null object), an NPE exception occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mistaken with the meaning of the `continue` keyword. This keyword means that the loop jumps immediately to the next iteration without executing the rest of the code in the loop block.

In your case, it means that this code

```
i = localFileInputStream.read();
if (i != -1)
    continue;
localFileInputStream.close();
if ((char) i == 'v') {
    i = localFileInputStream.read();
```

closes the inputStream, and then tries to read from it. You algorithm is not very clear because of all the continues, so I can't really tell you how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
        try {
            mr[getCurrentPosition()] = new ModelRenderer(localContext,
                    localContext.getAssets().open(RendererView.objName));
             dialog.cancle();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            Log.v("DemoRendererView", "loading model: " + e);
        }
    }
```

please check this...

Comment: not relevant. there is no rule for accessing assets from a thread or another.

Comment: Still having same problem. @njzk2 Any way for this

Answer (score 0):

you start with

```
try {
        i = localFileInputStream.read();
        if (i != -1)
            continue;
        localFileInputStream.close();
```

so, you are closing the stream and after that you are trying to read again from it. Also you are running this inside an infinite loop and exit from it only in a the `catch` section. Consider closing the stream after you are done reading it.